# Sorting name and id in C

Tags: c

Im trying to write a code that can sort names. So I have tried to write a program but its not working as I want it to. I want the names to sort alphabetic. I would also want to sort the id based on which id has the highest value. all help appreciated. Kinda new to C and coding in general!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct class {
  char gender[13];
  char name[13];
  int *id;
};

int compare(const void *s1, const void *s2)
{
  struct class  *e1 = (struct class *)s1;
  struct class *e2 = (struct class *)s2;
  int gendercompare = strcmp(e1->name, e2->name);
  if (gendercompare == 0)  
    return e2->gender - e1->gender;
  else
    return -gendercompare;
}

main()
{
  int i;
  int employeecount;

  struct class info[]={{"male","AAA",2000},{"female","BBB",1000},{"male","CCC",3000}};

  employeecount=3; 

  for (i = 0; i < employeecount; ++i)
    printf("%i\t%s\t%s\n", info[i].id, info[i].gender, info[i].name);
    printf("\n");

  qsort(info, 3, sizeof(struct class), compare);

  for (i = 0; i < employeecount; ++i)
    printf("%i\t%s\t%s\n", info[i].id, info[i].gender, info[i].name);
}
```

Comment: The structure member `id` is a *pointer*, but you initialize it as a *value* in your array. That actually leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since you use the wrong `printf` format to print the "pointers".

Comment: What are you trying to do with `return e2->gender - e1->gender`? it doesn't look right

Comment: Compile with warnings enabled and treat them as errors

Comment: Aside: conversion from `void*` doesn't need a cast, so you can write `const struct class *e1 = s1;` etc.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: @Jabberwocky i want the outcome to be   2000 male AAA
1000 female  BBB
300   male CCC. = sorted by their names

Comment: @L.P See anwers below. Upvote/accept them at your convenience.

Comment: Regarding: `main()`  there are two valid signatures for the `main()` function:  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, *argv[] )`  Notice that they both have a return type of `int`

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  amongst other things, it is missing the statement: `#include <string.h>` for the function: `strcmp()`

Comment: Per this:  `struct class {
  char gender[13];
  char name[13];
  int *id;
};`  the third member of the struct is an `pointer to int`  however, the initialization is showing the third member to be an `int`  This is a major problem in the posted code.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to perform the same activities

Comment: In C, the compiler does not know anything about any meaning to indenting the code. However, `gcc` will assume that the person doing the coding means that a looping statement (`for()`, `while()`, etc) followed by indented code means the person wants the indented lines to be grouped within the loop.  To actually include those indented lines as part of the loop, must enclose those lines with an opening brace '{' followed by the lines to be included in the loop, followed by a closing brace '};

Comment: regarding: `return e2->gender - e1->gender;`  In C, a string can only be compared with a function, like: `strcmp()`  in C, a reference to an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  This line only compares the address of the two different fields.  Suggest: `return  strcmp( e1->gender, e2->gender);`

Comment: in function: compare() regarding: `return -gendercompare;`  this will sort descending rather than the desired ascending order because of the `-` sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to update your `compare` function as follows:

```
#include <string.h>

struct class {
  char gender[13];
  char name[13];
  int id;
};

int compare(const void *s1, const void *s2)
{
  struct class *e1 = (struct class *)s1;
  struct class *e2 = (struct class *)s2;
  return strcmp(e1->gender, e2->gender);
}
```

The `strcmp` is enough to perform comparison.

Other minor details are mentioned very well in @Jabberwocky's answers.

Comment: I think he wants to sort by gender, and not by name (not entirely sure though...)

Comment: Thanks @Jabberwocky:  I updated the code. In such a case we can use strcmp too.

Comment: No, leave it, your answer was good (I upvoted it). I'm refering to your answer in my answer.

Comment: @ConsistentProgrammer

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems, see the `// <<<<` comments I added:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>   // <<<< you forgot to include string.h

struct class {
  char gender[13];
  char name[13];
  int id;            // <<<< int *id; having a pointer here is pointless,
                     //      you simple want an integer value here.
                     //      That's the main problem in your code
};

int compare(const void *s1, const void *s2)
{
  struct class *e1 = (struct class *)s1;
  struct class *e2 = (struct class *)s2;
  int gendercompare = strcmp(e1->name, e2->name);
  if (gendercompare == 0)
    return e2->gender - e1->gender;
  else
    return -gendercompare;
}

int main(void)   // <<<< it's int main(void) , not main()
{
  int i;
  int employeecount;

  struct class info[] = { {"male","AAA",2000},{"female","BBB",1000},{"male","CCC",3000} };

  employeecount = 3;

  for (i = 0; i < employeecount; ++i)
    printf("%i\t%s\t%s\n", info[i].id, info[i].gender, info[i].name);
  printf("\n");

  // <<<< use employeecount instead of 3, it's the same thing but it's more consistent.
  //      Not something that would prevent your code from working
  qsort(info, employeecount, sizeof(struct class), compare);

  for (i = 0; i < employeecount; ++i)
    printf("%i\t%s\t%s\n", info[i].id, info[i].gender, info[i].name);
}
```

There is also a logic problem in your `compare` function, it seems you want to sort by gender, males first.

As the compare function must return a value <0, 0 or >0 you can simply return the return value of `strcmp`. Also you don't need the casts, but `e1` and `e2` must be `const` as `s1` and `s2` are `const`.

```
int compare(const void *s1, const void *s2)
{
  const struct class *e1 = s1;
  const struct class *e2 = s2;
  return -strcmp(e1->gender, e2->gender);
}
```

See also ConsistentProgrammer's answer for a compare function that sorts by name.

Comment: Somewhat pedantic, but it's actually `*e1` and `*e2` that must be const (though we could make all four const, i.e. `const struct class *const e1`)

Answer (score 0):

Compile with more warnings enabled, to help you diagnose problems:

```
gcc -std=c17 -fPIC -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds         54908259.c    -o 54908259
54908259.c: In function ‘compare’:
54908259.c:14:23: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcmp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   int gendercompare = strcmp(e1->name, e2->name);
                       ^~~~~~
54908259.c: At top level:
54908259.c:21:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 main()
 ^~~~
54908259.c: In function ‘main’:
54908259.c:26:38: warning: initialization of ‘int *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   struct class info[]={{"male","AAA",2000},{"female","BBB",1000},{"male","CCC",3000}};
                                      ^~~~
54908259.c:26:38: note: (near initialization for ‘info[0].id’)
54908259.c:26:60: warning: initialization of ‘int *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   struct class info[]={{"male","AAA",2000},{"female","BBB",1000},{"male","CCC",3000}};
                                                            ^~~~
54908259.c:26:60: note: (near initialization for ‘info[1].id’)
54908259.c:26:80: warning: initialization of ‘int *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   struct class info[]={{"male","AAA",2000},{"female","BBB",1000},{"male","CCC",3000}};
                                                                                ^~~~
54908259.c:26:80: note: (near initialization for ‘info[2].id’)
54908259.c:31:14: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("%i\t%s\t%s\n", info[i].id, info[i].gender, info[i].name);
             ~^             ~~~~~~~~~~
             %ls
54908259.c:30:3: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
   for (i = 0; i < employeecount; ++i)
   ^~~
54908259.c:32:5: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
     printf("\n");
     ^~~~~~
54908259.c:37:14: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("%i\t%s\t%s\n", info[i].id, info[i].gender, info[i].name);
             ~^             ~~~~~~~~~~
             %ls
```